# How to Select Top 1000 words using TF-IDF Vector?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, tf-idf, sklearn-pandas, tfidfvectorizer

I have a Documents with 5000 reviews. I applied tf-idf on that document. Here **sample_data** contains 5000 reviews. I am applying tf-idf vectorizer on the sample_data with **one gram range**. Now I want to get the top 1000 words
from the sample_data which have **highest tf-idf values**. Could anyone tell me how to get the top words?

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tf_idf_vect = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1))
tf_idf_vect.fit(sample_data)
final_tf_idf = tf_idf_vect.transform(sample_data)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TF-IDF values depend on individual documents. You can get top 1000 terms based on their count (Tf) by using the [`max_features` parameter of TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html):

> max_features : int or None, default=None
>
> ```
> If not None, build a vocabulary that only consider the top
> max_features ordered by term frequency across the corpus.
> ```

Just do:

```
tf_idf_vect = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1), max_features=1000)
```

You can even get the `'idf'` (global term weights) from the `tf_idf_vect` after fitting (learning) of documents by using `idf_` attribute:

> idf_ : array, shape = [n_features], or None
>
> ```
>   The learned idf vector (global term weights) when use_idf is set to True,
> ```

Do this after calling `tf_idf_vect.fit(sample_data)`:

```
idf = tf_idf_vect.idf_
```

And then select the top 1000 from them and re-fit the data based on those selected features.

But you cannot get top 1000 by "**tf-idf**", because the tf-idf is the product of `tf` of a term in a single document with `idf` (global) of the vocabulary. So for same word which appeared 2 times in a single document will have twice the tf-idf than the same word which appeared in another document only once. How can you compare the different values of the same term. Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: Presumably OP wants to treat the 5000 reviews as separate documents, thus the 'document' they mention is really a corpus? And in that case TFIDF is well-defined.

Comment: @smci Sorry I do not understand. If the OP wants to treat each review as separate documents, so does he want top 1000 terms from each review separately?